# How to show json response as code not as a string in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, string

I get my article from database as json object. in this json I have my article data like title and body. I can show it in html page by {{title}} but my problem is about body. body contain HTML codes but the angular show it as string between 2 quotation. How can I solve it?

Angular controller code:

```
myApp.controller("articlePageController" , function($scope , $http        ,$location , $routeParams){
$http.get("/getArticle")
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.body = data["article"]["body"];
        $scope.title = data["article"]["title"];
    })
    .error(function(data){
        console.log("no");
        $scope.currentArticle = data;
    });
});
```

Html view:

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<p>{{body}}</p>
```

result:

```
 <p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9aOuF0-1KKY" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></p>
```

the html code in result does not work as html code
result image: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVZVj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCPBm.png)

Comment: You can take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: What's the problem you facing currently ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
<p ng-bind-html="body"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ng-bind-html to display html contents.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml